# Missing options in nvidia settings

Tags: nvidia-settings

My problem is that in "nvidia x server settings" options are lost. They are has only for the first time after a clean installation of the system and install nvidia driver, but after the restart they disappear. 
https://postimg.org/image/691htbu71/

P. S. I have notebook with 2 video cards: nvidia 740m and integrated.